# How do I implement Google Maps to work on Web, Andriod and iOS in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps, react-native-web

I am fairly new to React Native and I am trying to implement a map that can be used in Web, Android and iOS.

The resources I have found online, are for implementing Android and iOS with react-native-maps or just in Web with react-native-web-maps. Is there an easy way to incorporate all of them in React Native?

I am also using the Expo CLI to run the server. I have not run `npm run eject` to create the OS-specific files as I am trying to make the code as cross-platform as possible.

Comment: Did you find any solution, I am also interested to know, what pricing will get applied if we implement Google Maps on the web and apps from react native.
As per the documentation Google maps native SDK(https://developers.google.com/maps/billing-and-pricing/pricing#mobile-dynamic) is free unlimited but javascript SDK have some pricing (https://developers.google.com/maps/billing-and-pricing/pricing#dynamic-maps)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if any package works straight away for all environments but you can conditionally render map component for mobile and for web.

I have used these following packages in mobile and web versions of Expo app, they work pretty similarly and are easy to use and implement:
-mobile: `@react-navigation/native`
-web: `@react-google-maps/api`